# Is this an reasonable use case for storing JSON in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, database-design, extjs4, inventory-management

I understand that it is generally considered a "bad idea" to store JSON in a MySQL column due to the fact that it becomes difficult to maintain and is not easily searched, or otherwise queried. However, I feel that the scenario I have encountered in my application is a reasonable use case for storing JSON data in my MySQL table. I am indeed looking for an answer, particularly one that may point out any difficulties which I may have overlooked, or if there is any good reason to avoid what I have planned and if so, an alternate approach.

The application at hand provides resource and inventory management, and supports building Assemblies, which may contain an infinite number of sub assemblies.

I have a table which holds all of the metadata for items, such as their name, sku, retail price, dimensions, and most importantly to this question: the *item type*. An item can either be a *part* or an *assembly*. For items defined as *assemblies*, their contents are stored in another table, `item_assembly_contents` whose structure is rather expected, using a `parent_id` column to link the children to the parent. As you may expect, at any time, a user may decide to add or remove an item from an assembly, or otherwise modify the assembly contents or delete it entirely.

Here is a visual representation of the above table description, populated with data that when composed, creates an assembly containing another assembly. 
[image: Item and Assembly Table Structure]
With the above structure, any item that is deleted from the `items` table will also be automatically deleted in the `item_assembly_contents` table via InnoDB `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Here is a very simple example Assembly in JSON format, demonstrating a single Sub Assembly structure.

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"Fruit Basket",
   "type":"assembly",
   "contents":[
      {
     "id":10,
     "parent_id":1,
     "name":"Apple",
     "type":"part",
     "quantity":1
      },
      {
     "id":11,
     "parent_id":1,
     "name":"Orange",
     "type":"part",
     "quantity":1
      },
      {
     "id":12,
     "parent_id":1,
     "name":"Bag-o-Grapes",
     "type":"assembly",
     "quantity":1,
     "contents":[
        {
           "id":100,
           "parent_id":12,
           "name":"Green Grape",
           "quanity":10,
           "type":"part"
        },
        {
           "id":101,
           "parent_id":12,
           "name":"Purple Grape",
           "quanity":10,
           "type":"part"
        }
     ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The Fruit Basket is an Assembly, which contains a Sub-Assembly named "Bag o Grapes". This all works wonderfully, **until orders and shipments come into consideration**.

Take for example, an outbound shipment containing an assembly. At any time, the user must be able to see the contents of the assembly, ***as they were defined at the time of shipment***, which rules out simply retrieving the data from the `items` and `item_assembly_contents` table, as these tables may have been modified since the shipment was created. Therefore, assembly contents must be explicitly saved with the shipment so that they may be viewed at a later date, independent of the state or *mere existence* of the assembly in the user's defined inventory (that being, the `items` table).

It is storing the assembly contents along side the shipment contents that has me a bit confused, and where it seems to me that storing the data in JSON is a visable solution. It is critical to understand the following points about this data:

1. It will **NOT** be used for Searches
2. Any **UPDATES** will simply overwrite the contents of the row
3. It will **MOST OFTEN** be used to populate a Tree View on the Client, which will accept the JSON as it exists in the table, without any need for modification.

See this image for a (hopefully) more clear visualization of the data:
[image: Current vs Proposed Table Structure]

**Questions**

1. Is this a reasonable use case? Are my concerns meaningless?
2. Is there anything that I have looked over that may come back to bite me?
3. Can you provide an explanation why I should NOT proceed with my proposed schema, and if so....
4. Can you provide an alternative approach?

As always, thank you so much for your time and please do not hesitate to request clarification or additional information.

**UPDATE**
As per [@Rowland Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50447/rowland-shaw)'s suggestion (below), I've come up with another proposed table structure using a reflexive or "bunny ear" relationship to the order_assembly_contents table. Please see the following image:
[image: Updated Proposed Table Structure]

I feel this is a lot more elegant than storing the JSON directly, as the data is more relational and database friendly. Retrieving the data and forming it for the client should be easy-peasy as well! Please provide any input on the above structure!

Comment: If you're not going to store relational data, why use a relational database management system?  Why not just store your JSON files (that's what they are) in a highly optimised file storage database (i.e. your filesystem)?

Comment: @eggyal That's a really good point, and one of the reasons why I felt my proposed table structure to be an ugly solution. I would like to store this data in a relational manner, however I am struggling with how to structure the tables in a way that would allow me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, for an ordering system I'd expect something like

```
Product -< OrderLine >- Order
```

In your case, you could add a "bunny ear" relation on your Product to refer to itself. So your `outbound_shipment_contents` loses `name`, `type` to the new `product`. You can then recursively build up the tree of items to pick as required.

Comment: I'd like to avoid a bunny ear relation, as doing so would require me to sacrifice the FK restraint of `parent_id` -> `order_contents.id`. The reason for requiring an `Order_Contents` table to begin with is because I cannot point to the primary `Product` table, as this table will always be changing as the user adds/removes products from their library of product definitions. All orders and shipments must keep records of the items they contained which cannot rely on the existence of data in the `Product` table itself. I hope that makes sense, thank you very much for your helpful input!

Comment: I edited my question and added a new proposed table structure using a reflexive relationship. Do you feel this is a more elegant approach?

Comment: It certainly looks more elegant than storing JSON with your `outbound_shipment_contents` esentially being my `OrderLine` and your `outbound_shipment_assembly_contents` being my `Product` although I would have your Apple and Orange in there as well (just with no children), which means your wouldn't need the type on (at least) `outbound_shipment_contents` (arguably you can derrive that it's not an assembly by it not having child rows)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful input, I am much more confident now! I have accepted your answer as it certainly pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a standard bill of materials problem and there are lots of good articles on SQL and bill of materials patterns.  I would avoid the JSON storage as it really complicates any reporting and detailed joining functionality that relies on the native SQL.  For your application you can construct the JSON for the UI within a data access layer.

IMHO: Keep the data clean, highly accessible and relational in the relational db, repurpose for the application at the data access/low level business layer.

Comment: Thanks for the mention of Bill of Materials I am now reading into articles written on the subject. I do agree with your answer, I'm just not sure how to structure the DB around my needs? Any thoughts on the matter? Again, thank you!

Comment: I would abstract the schema to view the Order as the xref table between the Product and the assemblies and add the quantity attribute to it.  If your assemblies are going to be recursive (which I think they are) then you need to investigate SQL for recursion with a focus on the capabilities of your relational engine.  I see a relatively static set of product names in one table, a 'default' assembly list for the initial component load in another (or a attribute driven definition in the Order table) and then the Order table to handle the quantity/content edits to the default Product config.